# Summation of R in a function

Tags: r

[image]

This is the formula for the function. The dataset contains the variable k (row no.), t (0-120) and C.
I will like to apply a summation using N = 121.

My current written code is as follows: `x <- function(tk,tk_0,conc,conc_0){x <- 1/2*sum((conc+conc_0)*(tk-tk_0))}`

I am not so sure how to proceed forward with the code as I am supposed to write a function that takes time and concentration as arguments to calculate x

Answer (score 1):

Most calculation functions in R are vectorized meaning you don't have to write loops. If vector `C` contains your measurements at times `t_1, ..., t_N` and vector `t` contains time  then you can simply calculate your formula:

```
sum((tail(C,-1) + head(C,-1)) * diff(t)) / 2
```

`tail(x, -1)` removes first element of vector `x` and `head(x,-1)` removes last element of vector `x`. Function `diff` calculates differences. For more information you can write in R console `?tail`, `?head`, `?diff`.

Another way to calculate your sum is to notice that you want rolling mean of vector `C` of length 2. For rolling calculations you can use package `zoo`:

```
sum(zoo::rollmean(C, 2) * diff(t))
```

Comment: Hi det, thanks for the response! Is there a loop version to calculate the sum for this function?